# Custom EC2 utilization reports

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a way to generate EC2 utilization report which contains below selections (I need all of them in one report)

1. EC2 instance name
2. Current status (stopped/running)
3. Availability Zone
4. Region
5. Cost incurred for the current month.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no single report** that would contain that information.

If you want the "current" information about an instance, you'll need to make an API call, or use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws ec2 describe-instances` command. That will provide you with everything except cost.

You can use the [Cost and Usage Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports-costusage.html) to identify costs associated with particular instances (by Instance ID, not name).